# How to check menu option availability in android device?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-navigation, android-optionsmenu

I've developed an android application with Menu options. Unfortunately some devices don't have a menu option(soft or hard) availability to access menu options. We can detect hardware menu option availability using the following code:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

I didn't find a way to find the soft menu availability through program. 
My requirement is if the device doesn't have access to menu option(soft or hard) I need to display a message to the user with some information.

Here I've attached a screen which will explain the problem more precisely:
[image]

Comment: This is essentially the same question that you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405635/how-to-detect-soft-menu-key-available-in-android-device), isn't it ?

Comment: Explained problem here with clear information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ActionBar` (and you have at least one menu item not shown as action), the menu button (called overflowed menu explicitly) is always available on the `ActionBar`. Why do you mind?

It's totally under control of your (app developer's) hand. This issue does not belong to device side, does it?